# Devolver objeto JSON con PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, api

Estoy haciendo una aplicación sobre un restaurante, y necesito que cuando lance la consulta a la base de datos me devuelva objetos json que serán las cartas, que almacenará las categorias y sus productos he aqui la estructura del objeto deseado:

```
[
{
  name: 'Vegano',
  categorias: [
    {
      name: 'Entrantes',
      products: [
        { id: 0, name: 'Berenjena sticks', price: '8' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Remolacha', price: '5' }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Pizza',
      products: [
        { id: 0, name: 'Macarena', price: '8' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Sashimi', price: '5' }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]
```

He intentado varias consultas como por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    carta.nombre as name, jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_build_object(
            'name', categoria.nombre, 
            'image', categoria.foto, 
            'products', jsonb_build_object(
                'id', producto.id_producto, 
                'name', producto.nombre, 
                'price', producto.precio, 
                'image', producto.foto))) as categorias

FROM categoria
   
INNER JOIN carta ON carta.id_carta = categoria.id_carta
   
INNER JOIN producto ON producto.id_categoria = categoria.id_categoria
   
WHERE carta.id_restaurante = 1
   
GROUP BY carta.nombre;
```

Cuyo output es:

```
{
    "name":"Vegano",
    "categorias":
    [
        {
            "name":"Pizzas",
            "image":"https://www.recetasveganas.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Pizza-vegana.jpg",
            "products":
            {
                "id":3,
                "name":"Piña",
                "image":"https://www.hosteleriasalamanca.es/fotos/1533025888.6461.jpg",
                "price":20
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"Pizzas",
            "image":"https://www.recetasveganas.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Pizza-vegana.jpg",
            "products":
            {
                "id":4,
                "name":"Mini berenjenas",
                "image":"https://www.divinacocina.es/wp-content/uploads/mini-pizza-berenjena1.jpg",
                "price":18
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Como veis me salen categorias repetidas pero con diferentes productos, entonces no se en qué parte de la consulta está mal o que otra consulta podría utilizar ya que nunca habia hecho este tipo de consulta que devolviera un json.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿En qué versión de PostgreSQL estás trabajando?

Comment: No te está faltando una llamada a `jsonb_agg(` antes del segundo `build_object` para que _arme_ otro arreglo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que esta query retorna el json que querés. Al no conocer el modelo de datos y no contar con datos de prueba es dificil llegar al resultado esperado, pero sino te puede orientar para que escribas tu propia query.

Te recomiendo que en el futuro compartas la estructura de datos (preferiblemente los CREATE TABLE), y un conjunto mínimo de datos de prueba (INSERT queries), para poder probar la query; sino es dificil poder ayudar.

Lo que hice es ir construyendo el json de adentro hacía afuera usando subqueries.

```
SELECT json_agg(
           jsonb_build_object(
               'name', carta_nombre,
               'categorias', categorias)) AS cartas

FROM (
    SELECT 
        carta_nombre, 
        jsonb_agg(
            jsonb_build_object(
                    'name', categoria_nombre, 
                    'image', categoria_foto, 
                    'products', productos
        )) AS categorias

    FROM (
        SELECT 
            carta.nombre AS carta_nombre,
            categoria.nombre AS categoria_nombre,
            categoria.foto AS categoria_foto,
            jsonb_agg(
                jsonb_build_object(
                    'id', producto.id_producto, 
                    'name', producto.nombre, 
                    'price', producto.precio,
                    'image', producto.foto
                )) AS productos

        FROM categoria
        INNER JOIN producto ON producto.id_categoria = categoria.id_categoria
        INNER JOIN carta ON carta.id_carta = categoria.id_carta
        WHERE carta.id_restaurante = 1
        GROUP BY carta.nombre, categoria.nombre, categoria.foto) AS aux1

    GROUP BY carta_nombre) AS aux2;
```

Comment: Hola! muchisimas gracias ha funcionado! Y gracias también por tus comentarios la proxima vez aportare los datos que comentaste

Comment: De nada @kbarba! Me alegro que te haya sido util la query. Siempre ayuda conocer el modelo y contar con datos de prueba.

Comment: de nuevo muchisimas gracias por resolverme la duda, ahora el problema que me encuentro es que cuando creo una categoria, y hago la consulta no se me devuelve la categoria creada y creo que es por que no tiene productos creados dentro, he estado viendo que para estos casos se utiliza el **coalesce**, pero no sé como aplicarlo en este caso. Mil gracias

Comment: Para que te retorne las categorías que no tienen productos, deberías hacer un `LEFT JOIN` con producto, en lugar de un `INNER JOIN`, dicha categoría tendrá un producto con Id null. La función coalesce va a retornar el primer parámetro que no sea nulo, la puedes usar en este caso según como quieras obtener la información.